# $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k} < \ln 2$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, solution-verification, integral-inequality

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}  < \ln 2$

Here are some [proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2583575/547265) for this inequality but I have another approach. Can anyone verify my proof? Thanks.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}< \int_0^n \frac{1}{n+x}dx=\ln (n+x)\mid ^n_0 = \ln(2n)-\ln(n) = \ln 2.$$

Does the first inequality of this proof hold? In general, what's the relationship between a series and its integral form? Is the series always less than its integral form? Is it the same for a finite summation?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670508/solve-lim-n-to-infty-left-frac1n1-frac1n2-cdots-frac1nn?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a (French, but efficient) way of understanding how the comparison series/integrals work for decreasing functions. In your case
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}< \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{n+x-1}dx=\ln (n+x-1)\mid ^{n+1}_1 = \ln(2n)-\ln(n) = \ln 2.$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the graph! It is really helpful. May I know what software did you use to make that graph?

Comment: You're welcome. You can make such a graph using Geogebra. I didn't make this one myself.